# Format phone number in Zapier (code)

Tags: javascript, zapier

JS newbie here! Thanks in advance for the help!

I am trying to format a phone number in Zapier.  The data is coming in from a webhook and is typically of the format '2223334444'. I need to confirm this formatting and then add a 1 to the front of the number for use in the Twilio integration. [My attempted code is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrJ7o.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually format a phone number with the built-in Formatter: https://zapier.com/help/formatter/. It's a bit better than running it through a code step because the phone number will be validated and formatted according to whatever format/standard you select, even when the input format varies.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using regex:

```
function convertPhone(phone)
{
    if (!phone.match(/1?2{3}3{3}4{4}/)
        return null;
     // check in case humber has a prefix of 1:
     return phone.match(/$1.+/)? phone: 1 + phone;

}
```